# What does m in grep m{} mean in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

```
grep m{^[/!:]}, @imports
```

Anyone knows what `m` means here?

I don't find any reference .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mress-2:10005 Z$ perldoc -f m
       m//     The match operator.  See "Regexp Quote-Like Operators" in
               perlop.
```

Basically, if you need to use a `/` inside a pattern, it's easier to switch the pattern delimiters; but then you need to tell Perl you're doing that, so you start the pattern with `m`.  `/.../` can also be written `m/.../`.  Using `m` also means you can use balanced pairs `{...}`, `(...)`, `[...]`, `<...>` (but *not* brackets from outside ASCII such as guillemots or the math brackets in Unicode).

Comment: Note that some delimiters trigger special handling: ? and '

Comment: So grep and map can accept both pattern and code block as parameters?

Comment: @new_perl: no, this time the {} do not mean a code block.  Without the m in front, they would, but then there would not be a comma after the close brace.  The two forms for `grep` are: `grep BLOCK LIST` and `grep EXPR, LIST`.  This is an example of the latter.

Comment: It can; in fact, that was the original form, the block form being added later when a general rationalization of "indirect object syntax" (of which this is a special case) took place.

Comment: You can even use other symbols such as `#`, `\` or `|`. But I guess many people find brackets more readable.

Answer (score 3):

`m` is the match operator in Perl. You can read more [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch05_02.htm). Of particular value is that `{}` are not required: you can do `m//` or `m!!` and so on, which is useful if, in your case, the pattern itself had `{` or `}` in it.

Comment: No; the point of `m` is to allow you to specify a pattern delimiter other than `/`.  In this case, it's `{`; therefore `}` is the closing delimiter (see *Quote and Quote-like Operators* in `perldoc perlop`).

Comment: @new_perl: Because `{` is the first character following `m`, it opens the regex. Perl's `m` operator is smart and balances it with `}`

Comment: Normally `{}` would be a code block, but with the match operator (also the transliteration and substitution operators--`tr///` and `s///`) the `{` immediately following the `m` takes on the special meaning of delimiting the pattern. The link I posted goes into detail on what you can use and some special meanings that certain delimiters like `?` have.

Comment: So grep and map can accept both pattern and code block as parameters?

Comment: There is no code block here, just a pattern (`^[/!:]`) that happens to be using the same delimiter as a code block would.

Comment: No. The `m` operator tells Perl to interpret what follows as a pattern delimiter and perform a pattern match; so `m{...}` is a pattern wrapped in `{}`. If you stuck an `m` in front of the block used in `grep` or `map` then it would become a match regex instead (and probably throw a syntax error).

Comment: @new_perl: see [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html); yes, the two forms for `grep` are: `grep BLOCK LIST` and `grep EXPR, LIST`.

Comment: `grep` can take a pattern; `map` cannot. But you still seem to be confused about the whole thing; `m{}` is *not* a code block, it is a pattern match (thats what the `m` means), and `{}` is *not* a pattern match because it doesn't start with an `m`. (And just to confuse you further, a third meaning of `{}` is an anonymous hash, and because there's no special prefix like with `m{}` Perl sometimes guesses wrong, leading to sometimes needing `{; ...}` to make sure Perl parses a block instead of a hash ref.)

Comment: @geekosaur ,perldoc tells me map can also take a pattern,seems.